# How to display the selected items of jquery checkbox list along with the label when only the user selects that particular checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
 <form novalidate="novalidate" class="wpcf7-form" name="myForm"  id="myForm">
   <fieldset>
   <div class="form_field odd">
      <label for='desktop'>Desktops </label> 
      <div class="form-group">
         <select id="ms" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Made to Order(assembled)</option>
            <option value="2">HP/Compaq</option>
            <option value="3">IBM</option>
            <option value="4">Lenovo </option>
            <option value="5">etc</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form_field even">
      <label for='server'>Servers </label> 
      <div class="form-group">
         <select id="ms1" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">Made to Order(assembled)</option>
            <option value="2">Compaq</option>
            <option value="3">IBM</option>
            <option value="4">etc</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form_field odd">
   <label for='laptop'>Laptops </label> 
   <div class="form-group">
      <select id="ms2" multiple="multiple">
         <option value="1">HP/Compaq</option>
         <option value="2">IBM</option>
         <option value="3">Lenovo</option>
         <option value="4">Sony</option>
         <option value="5">Dell </option>
         <option value="6">etc</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your questions isn't very clear. Please be clearer. Also, can you show us what you already did so far ?

Comment: I have several checkbox in my page and i want that whatever the items are selected in respective checkbox that should be printed in a table form along with the label of the checkbox in a bootstrap modal on button click event. Please provide the solution. I am still looking for the solution.

Comment: is there any other way to get the label of the checkbox without using parent(). I am asking becuase i want the lable to be printed once the user selects the checkbox item and user can select any option

Comment: its not printing the checkbox label

Comment: Yes it is alerting the label..check out the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/958jm4uo/)

```
$("select[name='qwe'] option").click(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var label = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('label').text();
        var text = $(this).text();
        alert('option text is ' + text);
        alert('label text is ' + label);
    });
})
```

`UPDATE`

As @mplungjan suggested
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/958jm4uo/5/)

```
$("select[name='qwe']").change(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var text1 = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        var label1 = $(this).find('option:selected').parent().parent().parent().find('label').text();
        alert('option text is ' + text1);
        alert('label text is ' + label1);
    });
```

`UPDATE`

No `.parent()` with `.closest('div.classnameoftheparentdiv')`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/958jm4uo/7/)

```
$("select[name='qwe']").change(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var text1 = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        var label1 = $(this).find('option:selected').closest('div.form_field').find('label').text();//HERE parent div that contains the label has a class form_field
        alert('option text is ' + text1);
        alert('label text is ' + label1);
    });
})
```

Comment: I suggest using change rather than click

Comment: @mplungjan suggestion delivered. One question just to be  cleared by do you prefer change event than click? Is it just because this is option select?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Onclick is for buttons